# get latest column value from hive table conditionally on other columns

Tags: sql, hive, impala

I have a Hive table 'Orders' with four columns (id String, name String, Order String, ts String). Sample data of table is as below.

```
-------------------------------------------
id  name    order               ts
------------------------------------------- 
1   abc     completed       2018-04-12 08:15:26     
2   def     received        2018-04-15 06:20:17
3   ghi     processed       2018-04-16 11:36:56
4   jkl     received        2018-04-05 12:23:34
3   ghi     received        2018-03-23 16:43:46
1   abc     processed       2018-03-17 18:39:22
1   abc     received        2018-02-25 20:07:56
```

The Order column has three states received -> processed -> completed. There are many orders for a single name and each has these three stages. I need the latest value of order for a given 'id' and 'name'. This may seem as a novice question for you but I am stuck with this.

I tried writing queries like below but they are not working and I couldn't use max function directly on 'ts' column as it is in String format. Please advice a best method. 
Thanks in advance.

Queries I tried

```
SELECT
ORDER
FROM Orders
WHERE id = '1'
    AND name = 'ghi'
    AND ts = (
        SELECT max(unix_timestamp(ts, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS'))
        FROM Orders
        )
```

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 2:0 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'max' '(' in expression specification

```
SELECT
ORDER
FROM Orders
WHERE id = '1'
    AND name = 'ghi'
    AND max(unix_timestamp(ts, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS'))
```

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10128]: Line 1:93 Not yet supported place for UDAF 'max'

```
select o.order  from Orders o
inner join ( 
    select id, name, order, max(ts) as ts
    from Orders
    group by id, name, order
) ord on d.id = ord.id and o.name = ord.name and o.ts = ord.ts where o.id = '1' and o.name = 'abc'
```

This query was executed but the output is not a single latest order stage but of each order stage with corresponding latest timestamp.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given order, you want one row.  Hence, you can use `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM Orders o
WHERE id = 1 AND  -- presumably id is a number
     name = 'ghi'
ORDER BY ts DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This should also have the best performance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try the above query and get back. All the columns are of String type.

Comment: I want value of order column only. your query is giving me entire row. could you please tell any other way to find it

Comment: @RSG . . . If you want only one column, then select that column instead of `*`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RANK analytical function to get your problem resolved as below:

```
select id,name,order,ts
from (select id,name,order,ts,rank() over(partition by id,name order by ts) r from orders)k
where r = 1
and id = '1'
and name = 'ghi'
```

If you want to get the latest record for all the ID's and name then you don't need to pass the values for "ID" and "NAME" you will get your desired result easily.

All the best!!!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need the record for a particular id and name, Is there any way I can use above query and get the desired output

Comment: The will that I posted will return the row for particular ID,NAME only with latest timestamp, Does it not returning?